# Natural language query preprocessing

Tags: nlp, information-retrieval

I am trying to implement a natural language query preprocessing module which would, given a query formulated in natural language, extract the keywords from that query and submit it to an Information Retrieval (IR) system.

At first, I thought about using some training set to compute tf-idf values of terms and use these values for estimating the importance of single words. But on second thought, this does not make any sense in this scenario - I only have a training collection but I dont have access to index the IR data. Would it be reasonable to only use the idf value for such estimation? Or maybe another weighting approach?

Could you suggest how to tackle this problem? Usually, the articles about NLP processing that I read address training and test data sets. But what if I only have the query and training data?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "keywords" and "submit it to an IR system"?

Comment: There is an Information retrieval system (like Google) that, given a query returns results... I want to extract the most important words from a query written in natural language and use these words as a new query for this retreival system in order to obtain better results...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tf-idf  (it's not capitalized, fyi) is a good choice of weight. Your intuition is correct here. However, you don't compute tf-idf on your training set alone. Why? You need to really understand what the tf and idf mean:

tf (term frequency) is a statistic that indicates whether a term appears in the document being evaluated. The simplest way to calculate it would simply be a boolean value, i.e. 1 if the term is in the document.

idf (inverse document frequency), on the other hand, measures how likely a term appears in a random document. It's most often calculated as the log of (N/number of document matches).

Now, tf is calculated for each of the document your IR system will be indexing over (if you don't have the access to do this, then you have a much bigger and insurmountable problem, since an IR without a source of truth is an oxymoron). Ideally, idf is calculated over your entire data set (i.e. all the documents you are indexing), but if this is prohibitively expensive, then you can random sample your population to create a smaller data set, or use a training set such as the Brown corpus.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I understand how tf-idf works but the problem is, that I only have training set and set of queries to be preprocessed. So the quesion is - is tf-idf (or just idf) a correct approach to identify the keywords in the queries? I do not have access to the IR system and I cannot index its data (they are already indexed, but I cant get hold of those values...)

Comment: If you don't have access to the data set (I'm guessing this is a class assignment?), then you can calculate idf based on your training set. The tf, however, must be calculated off of a real document that you are scoring, since it's specific to that document.

Comment: If this is not an assignment, i.e. you'd NEVER see the real documents, then it gets a little trickier. Depending on how your data is indexed, you can still calculate tf based on the information in the index (keywords, tags, etc.). However in this case, tf-idf weighting loses much of its usefulness since the index data is likely already relevant to the document. I'd suggest PageRank as a good next step if this is the case.

Comment: It is sort of assignment but it is meant to give some feedback and possible improvements to already existing IR system. They have their sets indexed (I suppose) and I can send queries to this system and retreive the results (I cannot, however, work with the whole set). The purpose of my work is develop a system that reformulates NLP queires into standard queries in terms of using only some keywords from this, otherwise long, NLP query...

Comment: Would selecting the keywords only based on idf (and ignorig the tf part completely) make ANY sense in this scenario?

Comment: If the keywords actually occur in the document, then sure. It's rough, but it makes sense. Of course you also have to make sure the keywords are relevant to your query.

Comment: There is no problem capitalizing TF-IDF.